# Почему блок не центирируется в дочернем блоке grid?

Tags: html, css

Хочу в блоке с классом "a" разместить компоненты и чтобы поверх их в этом же блоке открывалось модальное окно в родительском блоке display: fixed;

Вот код:

```html
<div style="display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;grid-gap: 0.5rem;">
  <div>asa</div>
  <div class="a">
    <div style="position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;display: flex;">
      <div style="margin: auto;">heello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Получается вот так, но heello не по центру второго блока.
[image]

Как это решить?

Comment: почему вы решили, что он не центрует?

Answer (score 0):

что бы центрировать элемент вы забыли добавить align-items: center; justify-content: center; в родительский див(в котором див с heello лежит)

```html
<body>
     <div style="display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;grid-gap: 0.5rem;">
    <div>asa</div>
    <div>
        <div style="position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
            <div style="margin: auto;">heello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: посмотрите внимательнее, ваш вариант по результату ничем не отличается от того, что получилось у автора вопроса

Comment: я у себя в браузере делал и все хорошо там получилось

Comment: а вы попробуйте блоку, в котором текст `heello` добавить например `border: 2px solid red;` и задать `width` в `90%` и посмотрите на результат

Answer (score 0):

У вас все центрируется, но вы зачем то используете `position: fixed` и задаете размер, из-за чего ваш блок выходит за пределы области видимости. Вы же задали grid-разметку с динамическими размерами, она сама растянет блоки до конца:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>asa</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <div>heello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

и еще непонятно зачем вы делаете такой бутерброд из вложенных `div`-ов, если вы их не используете. Уберите их, если они вам не нужны, меньше будете путаться в своем коде. Т.е. для вашего примера вполне достаточно написать так:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>asa</div>
    <div class="content">heello</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: position: fixed нужен для модального окна в этом блоке поверх других компонентов в этом блоке